# Ruby leaves zombies and how to manage command executions

Tags: ruby, linux, multithreading, command

I need to call commands sporadically in my ruby app, most commands will end quite quickly, but some will run for longer (like playing a song) and I need to be able to kill that process if wanted.
The commands are called in a sub thread as not to lock the rest of the app.

I also need to store info on running commands (so I know what to kill if needed), but I also need to send out info when the command ended.

**The problems:**
`wait` or `waitpid` doesn't work (they never return)
I tried to use `trap`, which detects when the command ended, but it only works for the latest started command.
Ruby leaves the commands as zombie process (until killing the app) and trying to use the `kill`(both `Process.kill` and calling the command directly) doesn't remove them. (Perhaps the reason to why `wait` doesn't work??)

```
# Play sound (player can be either 'mplayer' or 'aplay' )
pid = spawn player, sound_dir + file

Eddie::common[:commands][:sound_pids][pid] = file

Signal.trap("CLD") {
  # This runs, but doesn't clean up zombies
  Process.kill "KILL", pid
  p = system 'kill ' + pid.to_s

  Eddie::common[:commands][:sound_pids].delete pid
}
```

If I run this twice (once while the first command is running) it will look like this after both commands ended:

```
Eddie::common[:commands][:sound_pids] => {3018=>"firstfile.wav"}
```

and this is the result of `ps`

```
chris     3018  0.0  0.0      0     0 pts/5    Z+   23:50   0:00 [aplay] <defunct>
chris     3486  0.2  0.0      0     0 pts/5    Z+   23:51   0:00 [aplay] <defunct>
```

**Added note:** Using `system` to call the command doesn't leave a zombie process, but in turn it's not killable..